# Needs clarification on React native sendIntent()

Tags: javascript, react-native

In react native , can we open a particular with this? And what is the use of `extra` here

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Alert, Button, Linking, StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";

const SendIntentButton = ({ action, extras, children }) => {
  const handlePress = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      await Linking.sendIntent(action, extras);
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert(e.message);
    }
  }, [action, extras]);

  return <Button title={children} onPress={handlePress} />;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SendIntentButton action="android.intent.action.POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY">
        Power Usage Summary
      </SendIntentButton>
      <SendIntentButton
        action="android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"
        extras={[
          { "android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE": "com.facebook.katana" },
        ]}
      >
        App Notification Settings
      </SendIntentButton>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" },
});

export default App;
```

Trying to understand intent in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When on Android this will open the notifications in settings. `extras` provides the app for which you want to edit the notification settings. More on this in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE) for this property.

Usually, this extras should include the identifier of your app.